# Can't connect to Redis Stack from GO application inside a container

Tags: docker, go, redis

I have a GO REST API application and using redis stack and postgreSQL as main databases. I am able to connect to the postgres database but cannot connect to the redis stack database, it refuses to connect for some reason (it works on local development but refuses to connect inside the container). Here is my code to connect and my docker-compose file for reference.

Connection to Redis Stack Code (Using [go-rejson](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/nitishm/go-rejson) Package)

```
func getRedisDbConnection() (*redis.Client, *rejson.Handler) {
redisDb := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
    Addr:     viper.GetString("REDIS_DB_HOST") + viper.GetString("REDIS_DB_PORT"),
    Password: viper.GetString("REDIS_DB_PASSWORD"),
    DB:       viper.GetInt("REDIS_DB_NAME"),
})
_, err := redisDb.Ping().Result()
if err != nil {
    log.Println("Can't connect with Redis database", "Errors:", err)
} else {
    log.Println("Redis Db is connected", "Errors:", err)
}
redisJsonDb := rejson.NewReJSONHandler()
redisJsonDb.SetGoRedisClient(redisDb)

return redisDb, redisJsonDb
}
```

App.env file:

```
 # Server
 SERVER_PORT=:8888

 # config
 DEVELOPMENT=true

 # Redis DB
 REDIS_DB_HOST=redis
 REDIS_DB_PORT=:6378
 REDIS_DB_PASSWORD=
 REDIS_DB_NAME=0#Default DB

 # PG DB
 PG_DB_HOST=postgres
 PG_DB_PORT=5432
 PG_DB_USER=postgres
 PG_DB_PASSWORD=38043
 PG_DB_NAME=postgres

 # Rabbitmq
 RABBITMQ_HOST=rabbitmq
 RABBITMQ_PORT=:5672
```

docker-compose.yaml (format is abit off here)

```
version: "3.3"
services:
 postgres:
    container_name: student-grades
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
        POSTGRES_USER: postgres
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 38043
        POSTGRES_DB: postgres
    ports:
        - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
        - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data

 redis:
   container_name: exam-db
   image: redis/redis-stack
   ports:
     - "6378:6378"
     - "8001:8001"
   volumes:
     - redisdata:/var/lib/redis/data
   restart: unless-stopped

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    container_name: RabbitMQ
    volumes:
       - rabbit-data:/data/rabbit
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    restart: unless-stopped

 exam-service:
    container_name: exam-service
    image: eyadzz/dexam_exam_service
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
   depends_on:
      - "postgres"
   links:
      - "postgres"
volumes:
  redisdata:
  pgdata:
  rabbit-data:
```

Error Message:

> 2022/07/03 18:22:01.012088 driver.go:27: Can't connect with Redis database Errors: dial tcp 172.23.0.4:6378: connect: connection refused

Can anyone spot the problem?

Comment: Did you verify if the redis container is up?

Comment: Yes it's up and says accepting connection in the logs, I added more info to the question if it helps

Comment: Try connecting to redis externally, and then manually from one of the containers. It says connection refused, suggesting redis is not listening. Maybe wrong port?

Comment: I do not think the port is the problem as it was connecting and working fine locally before dockerizing the app, but I'll try again your suggestion.

Comment: It looks like it may simply be a race condition. Consider: what happens if you Go program tries to connect to redis before redis is ready to accept connections? Potentially a simple retry loop in your client code would take care of the problem.

Comment: Also, unrelated to your problem: it's very uncommon to require people to include the `:` as part of the port variable. Consider dropping that requirement and building `redisDB.Addr` using `fmt.Sprintf` instead (`Addr: fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s", viper.GetString("REDIS_DB_HOST"), viper.GetString("REDIS_DB_PORT")),`).

Comment: Redis's normal port number is 6379, not 6378.  You need to use that standard port number in `REDIS_DB_PORT` and also as the second `ports:` number.

Comment: Changing port number to 6379 inside the app.env file fixed the problem somehow, even though I used to connect to 6378 normally without having issues. Thanks a lot for your comment

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I did not have a Redis client for Windows.

I downloaded it from here https://github.com/microsoftarchive/redis/releases

Also added the path variables to the environment.

Then my Go app successfully connected to the Redis Docker container.